# Python Requests - any reason to not have private key in one file with client certificate?

Tags: python, security, ssl, python-requests, tls1.2

Python requests allows you to define a client certificate and private key with the cert argument in requests.request()

For the key, you can either add, give it in the beginning of the client cert file or give it as a tuple of two file paths (from docs: "as a single file (containing the private key and the certificate) or as a tuple of both files’ paths" ).

Why would one choose one option over the other here?

Comment: The private key should always be separate from the certificate. The one is private, the other is public.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne, is this a style thing or an actual functional security issue in this case with py requests?

Comment: It is a security issue.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne could you be more specific - in what ways is this a security issue?